# Struggling to print objects in Python using list comprehension

Tags: python, list, object, oop, list-comprehension

I am learning Python for the first time and am trying to build a full fledged object oriented program, based on a childhood nursery rhyme/game about counting fists (Bubblegum Bubblegum in a Dish...)

I have a class/Player object, which has fists as an attribute. There is a fist class. My issue is, I cannot figure out how to get the 'fists' of each player object to print because the fists are objects. I tried using a list comprhension and also **str** and **repr** overrides with the list comprehension, and no dice. Below is the code associated with my most recent attempt... I would appreciate if someone could show/explain to me where I am going wrong. Thanks for your time!

The result of my most recent attempt is this:
[<**main**.Fist object at 0x7f3d73f7e280>, <**main**.Fist object at 0x7f3d73f7e3a0>]
[<**main**.Fist object at 0x7f3d73f7e490>, <**main**.Fist object at 0x7f3d73f7e4f0>]

```
  class Fist:
   
   Labels = ['Left', 'Right']
   
    # Constructor for fists
   def __init__(self, label):
        self.label = label  # this is just for testing purposes
        
   
   # Overriding Python Built in Functions so Our Objects Print Cleanly
   
   def __str__(self):
       return f"{self.label}"


class Player():
    
    # 1 - Player creates player objects for EACH player specified
    # by the user. 
    
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.fists = [] # like deck, this holds fists
        
    
     # 2 - All users start out with TWO fists, so let's create those fists below:
    
        for Label in Fist.Labels:
           self.fists.append(Fist(Label))
           # print(self.fists.Fist.label)
            
        
    # 3 - The amount of fists remaining PER USER is kept track of
    # - When any player reaches a fist count of zero, they are
    # knocked out immedately
    
    def check_fist_count(self):
            if self.fists == 0:
             print(f'{self.name} fist count is now zero. They now are out of the game!')
             
           
             
     # Overriding Python Built in Functions so Our Objects Print Cleanly
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name + ': ' + ' '.join([str(fist) for fist in self.fist])
        
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    # Ask the user for the number of players, create one player object per player
    # If players entered are 0 or 1 terminate
    
    numberOfPlayers = int(input("Bubblegum Nursery Rhyme Game: How many players will be playing this game?"))
    
    if numberOfPlayers <= 1 :
        print('Sorry, you can only play this game if you have a minimum of 2 players.')
    
    # Create the players based on the numberOfPlayers
    game_players = []
    for i in range(0,numberOfPlayers):
        game_players.append(Player(f'Player {i}'))
        

# Print tests on fists
 
for game_player in game_players:
  
 print(game_player.fists)
 
 #print([str(item) for item in game_player.fists])
```

Comment: Are you sure? Changing `__str__` to `__repr__` works fine for me.

Comment: `Player.__str__` only gets called on `print(game_player)`, but you have `print(game_player.fists)`. There also is a missing`s` in the comprehension `for fist in self.fist`, should be `self.fists`.

Comment: @BRemmelzwaal - doesn't work for me. Gives me objects like this <main.Fist object at 0x7f3d73f7e3a0> only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were actually pretty close! You just need to add a `__repr__` special method to your classes, as the string formatting calls that method. Here is a way to fix the code:

```
class Fist:
   
   Labels = ['Left', 'Right']
   
    # Constructor for fists
   def __init__(self, label):
        self.label = label  # this is just for testing purposes
        
   
   # Overriding Python Built in Functions so Our Objects Print Cleanly
   
   def __str__(self):
       return f"{self.label}"
   
   def __repr__(self):
       return f"Fist({self.label})"


class Player():
    
    # 1 - Player creates player objects for EACH player specified
    # by the user. 
    
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.fists = [] # like deck, this holds fists
        
    
     # 2 - All users start out with TWO fists, so let's create those fists below:
    
        for Label in Fist.Labels:
           self.fists.append(Fist(Label))
           # print(self.fists.Fist.label)
            
        
    # 3 - The amount of fists remaining PER USER is kept track of
    # - When any player reaches a fist count of zero, they are
    # knocked out immedately
    
    def check_fist_count(self):
            if self.fists == 0:
             print(f'{self.name} fist count is now zero. They now are out of the game!')
             
           
             
    # Overriding Python Built in Functions so Our Objects Print Cleanly
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name + ': ' + ' '.join([str(fist) for fist in self.fists])
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Player({self.name}, {self.fists})"
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    # Ask the user for the number of players, create one player object per player
    # If players entered are 0 or 1 terminate
    
    numberOfPlayers = int(input("Bubblegum Nursery Rhyme Game: How many players will be playing this game?"))
    
    if numberOfPlayers <= 1 :
        print('Sorry, you can only play this game if you have a minimum of 2 players.')
    
    # Create the players based on the numberOfPlayers
    game_players = []
    for i in range(0,numberOfPlayers):
        game_players.append(Player(f'Player {i}'))
        

# Print tests on fists
 
for game_player in game_players:
    print(game_player)
 
 #print([str(item) for item in game_player.fists])
```

Comment: I truly appreciate your kind reply to my question - it worked as expected and helped me to understand where I went wrong. I am new to all of this and have had many experiences of people being rude and or making fun of my beginner questions on this site - it was so refreshing to get such a kind reply - thank you!

Comment: @JulieS beginner questions are just as valid as expert questions. The important thing is being very clear about the current and expected result and any possible errors, and your question was clear enough for me to answer.